# Netty HashedWheelTimer unexpected behaviour. Timeout triggers beforehand

Tags: java, timer, timeout

Lets consider the situation:

```
import org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer;
import org.jboss.netty.util.Timer;
import org.jboss.netty.util.Timeout;
import org.jboss.netty.util.TimerTask;


Timer timer = new HashedWheelTimer();
Timeout timeout = null;

void establishTimeout() {
    timeout = timer.newTimeout(timerTask, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

void cancelTimeout() {
    timeout.cancel()
    timeout = null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    establishTimeout();
    cancelTimeout();
    Thread.sleep(sleepDelay);
    establishTimeout();
}
```

What is happening on the timeline:

```
0          : establishTimeout(), cancelTimeout()
sleepDelay : establishTimeout()
delay      : timerTask.run()
```

Why timerTask runs not at the `sleepDelay + delay`?
How to make it work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Because `delay` is interpreted as seconds and `sleepDelay` is interpreted as milliseconds. Use `sleepDelay * 1000` to get the result you want.

```
public class TaskTester {

    static Timer timer = new HashedWheelTimer();
    static Timeout timeout = null;
    static int delay = 3;
    static int sleepDelay = 2;
    static TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask(){
        public void run(Timeout timeout) throws Exception {
            System.out.printf("RUN %.3f%n", System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000.0);
        }
    };

    static void establishTimeout() {
        timeout = timer.newTimeout(timerTask, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    static void cancelTimeout() {
        timeout.cancel();
        timeout = null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.printf("START %.3f%n", System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000.0);
        establishTimeout();
        cancelTimeout();
        Thread.sleep(sleepDelay * 1000);
        establishTimeout();
        System.out.printf("MAIN DONE %.3f%n", System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code in the question is abstract, therefore line: "Thread.sleep(sleepDelay);" just represents some delay in real code. And be sure, that `delay` and `sleepDelay` are proportional ;)

Comment: I updated my answer to include the code, which works as expected, so there must be something about your situation that's not reflected in your question.